/bin/sh: 1: node: not found in terminal when running node js on raspberry pi
Main goal
I am trying to run the onboard code from https://github.com/Pexeus/LTE-Car?tab=readme-ov-file. I have installed nodejs v14.21.3 using nvm onto a fresh 64 bit raspberry pi 4 model B. I have followed the readme instructions to the best of my experience, albeit very limited. I have installed pigpio and socat as covered in the github readme. After running npm install into the onboard folder, I run the program (elevated with sudo, see below). It connects, but when I click start from the webserver interface, the /bin/sh error appears. I have no experience in this area, any guidance would be appreciated.
All code has been run from Raspberry Pi terminal.
After running npm install, I tried running as called in the readme.
Non-Elevated Approach
This is based on code from the readme
test@raspberrypi:~/Documents/LTE car/LTE-Car-main/onboard $ node index.js
standby service ready [192.168.1.126]

[LTE-Car Error]: 2024-09-23 10:22:39 initCheckPermitted: 
+---------------------------------------------------------+
|Sorry, you don't have permission to run this program.    |
|Try running as root, e.g. precede the command with sudo. |
+---------------------------------------------------------+



[LTE-Car Error]: /home/test/Documents/LTE car/LTE-Car-main/onboard/node_modules/pigpio/pigpio.js:54
    pigpio.gpioInitialise();
           ^

Error: pigpio error -1 in gpioInitialise
    at initializePigpio (/home/test/Documents/LTE car/LTE-Car-main/onboard/node_modules/pigpio/pigpio.js:54:12)
    at new Gpio (/home/test/Documents/LTE car/LTE-Car-main/onboard/node_modules/pigpio/pigpio.js:158:5)
    at pin (/home/test/Documents/LTE car/LTE-Car-main/onboard/driver/control.js:53:12)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/test/Documents/LTE car/LTE-Car-main/onboard/driver/control.js:3:18)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1114:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1143:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:979:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:819:12)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1003:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:107:18)

Elevated Approach
Based on the guidance in the error, I tried running as with elevated access
Attempt without absolute node path
test@raspberrypi:~/Documents/LTE car/LTE-Car-main/onboard $ sudo node index.js
sudo: node: command not found

The Raspberry Pi did not connect at all in this case.
Attempt with absolute node path
Based on some interaction with ChatGPT, I tried the absolute node path
test@raspberrypi:~/Documents/LTE car/LTE-Car-main/onboard $ sudo /home/test/.nvm/versions/node/v14.21.3/bin/node index.js
standby service ready [192.168.1.126]
[LTE-Car Error]: /bin/sh: 1: node: not found`

The absolute path was obtained by running:

`test@raspberrypi:~/Documents/LTE car/LTE-Car-main/onboard $ which node
/home/test/.nvm/versions/node/v14.21.3/bin/node


This is something to first ask over on https://github.com/Pexeus/LTE-Car/issues - if you're following the instructions to the letter, and it doesn't do what the docs say should happen, you should ask the people who made this thing about that, so they know there's a problem, and can fix it for everyone using their project.

Thanks for the guidance, I have added an issue to the github. I am leaving this up since I am thinking that it could still be something wrong with my setup.

Your test user manages node versions with nvm, but your root user is completely separate from that. You should either install nodejs/nvm globally so root can make use of it, or you should figure out which gpio device you actually need and make sure your regular user has access. Running stuff as root is not a best practice.

root probably has a different $PATH than your regular used. That makes it a Unix config question, not a programming question IMHO. And like Botje said, you shouldn't need or use sudo / root anyway.
